# Android Kotlin - Serialize mutableList

Tags: android, kotlin

This is the model I have so far:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import java.io.Serializable


class Memes (
    @SerializedName("id") var id: Long,
    @SerializedName("title") var title: String
)
```

I need to make it serializible so I can pass it through activities.

When I change it to:

```
class Memes: Serializable {
    var id: Long,
    var title: String
}
```

then I get `Property getter or setter expected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin you have to instantiate properties with backing field in the construction (getting them from constructor, assigning them some value, or fill them in `init` blocks). And the only exception is `lateinit var`. In the first code, you're getting them in constructor. But in second one, they're introduced without being initialize so compiler asks you to either fill them, or convert them to non-backing field by providing getter and setters.

But if you want to make the first code Serializable you have to simply make that implement `Serializable` like this:

```
class Memes (
    @SerializedName("id") var id: Long,
    @SerializedName("title") var title: String
) : Serializable
```

Also it seems that you can turn it into a `data class`, so I suggest you to do it!